# Jquery autocomplete doesn't trigger with javascript set input value

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using the categories autocomplete. It works fine if I type into the input field directly. However, if I use javascript to set a value to the input field, the autocomplete doesn't trigger.

Widget portion is identical to [jqueryui site](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories).
Here's a [sample jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/15gj2qzp/2)

```
//sample HTML
<input id="search">
<button id="button">Click</button>

//sample JS
$(document).on("keyup", '#search', function(event){
   $.ajax{
      ...
      autocomplete_data = ajax_provided_data;
      $("#search").catcomplete({
         source: function(request, response){
            console.log("source");
            response(autocomplete_data);
         },
         select: function(event, ui){
            //do stuff
         }
      });
   }
});

$(document).on("click", "#button", function(event){
   $("#search").val("abcd");
   $("#search").keyup();
});
```

When I click `#button`, the input's value is changed, the `keyup()` is triggered, and the ajax runs. However, the `catcomplete()` doesn't trigger. It never makes to console.log in `source` function.
If I manually type into the input field, everything works just fine, and it will print "source" in console.

I have also tried [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/91298/how-to-set-value-of-autocomplete-field-and-trigger-search-event-with-jquery) to trigger a space keypress. Still no luck.

It will work, however, if I click the button, then manually type space into the input field.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at `jquery-ui.js` autocomplete section. In order to trigger the full autocomplete functions, `keydown` or `input` event needs to happen.

By modifying [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/91349), changing the `keyup` to `keydown`, and it'll work.

```
function ShowAutoComplete($field, searchVal) {
   var e = $.Event('keydown');
   e.which = 32;
   $field.val(searchVal).focus().trigger(e);
}
```

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/15gj2qzp/4/)